com.simplemobiletools.commons library not loading without jcenter
I am using a library
implementation ('com.simplemobiletools:commons:5.32.23')

It was working with jcenter. But now it is not even working with jcenter(). I am getting this error:
Could not find commons-5.32.23.aar (com.simplemobiletools:commons:5.32.23).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/simplemobiletools/commons/5.32.23/commons-5.32.23.aar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/simplemobiletools/commons/5.32.23/commons-5.32.23.jar

As recommended by Android and importing its alternate Maven version. I am able to find the library in Maven here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.simplemobiletools/commons
But when I import it in Android, it fails to load and says "Failed to resolve com.simplemobiletools:commons:1.0.12"
Why is that? I need to remove jcenter and use its alternate Maven version.
I have added this in my settings.gradle
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
    }
}

I have this in my projectName/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        }
    }
....

And I have added this in app/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
//        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
//        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.7.0'
    }
}

Plus, first I was getting error "Failed to resolve: com.simplemobiletools:filepicker:1.6.1"
Then I excluded filepicker like:
implementation ('com.simplemobiletools:commons:1.0.12') {         
   exclude module:'filepicker' 
   exclude module: 'joda-time'
 }

then I started to get Failed to resolve com.simplemobiletools:commons:1.0.12

Do you have mavenCentral() as an artifact repository set up for Gradle? You might consider editing your question and providing the full Gradle output where the "could not resolve" message appears.

I was able to resolve com.simplemobiletools:commons:1.0.12 fine but it appears that that library depends on com.simplemobiletools:filepicker:1.6.1 which does not appear to exist

@CommonsWare I have editted the question

@tyczj I have editted the question, please check
